# Detokenization for Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: java, python-3.x, stanford-nlp, pycorenlp

I have used stanford coreNLP's tokenizer to tokenize sentences into tokens. Now I need to detokenize the already tokenized words (i.e I need reverse tokenizer for standford coreNLP.) Is there any JAVA class in standfordcoreNLP or java/python API which we can use?

```
I/P:

I ca n't use this pen .
I have ( 5 ) points to explain .
I have discuss the 1,2,3 etc. ..

O/P: 

I can't use this pen.
I have (5) points to explain.
I have discuss the 1,2,3 etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Sentence` class from the Simple API, has multiple constructors, [one of which](https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/simple/Sentence.html#Sentence-java.util.List-) takes a `List<String>` argument.

So you can do something like:

```
List<String> words = new Sentence("I can't use this pen.").words();
Sentence output = new Sentence(words);
```

Comment: Thank you Manos Nikolaidis for your valuable suggestion. I will explore this